# Pass variable via curl with python script

Tags: python, curl, flask

I am trying to pass a variable's content via curl to my Flask app. From what i found we can pass a variable via curl like this:

`url -X POST -d "{\"variable_name\": \"${variable_content}\"}" 0.0.0.0:5000/query --header "Content-Type:application/json"`

which works.

Now i am using this exact curl command in a subprocess:

```
subprocess.call('curl -X POST -d "{\"variable_name\": \"${variable_content}\"}" 0.0.0.0:5000/query --header "Content-Type:application/json"', shell=True)
```

This is the error i am getting and i cannot find a workaround.

Failed to decode JSON object: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 2 (char 1)

Comment: Note that you have to escape certain symbols once for python, and once for curl.  Add an `r` in front of your string to make it a "[raw string literal](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals)" to remove one of those layers of escaping.

Comment: Good catch 0x5453!

Comment: Thank you for the response, can you give me a quick example ?

Comment: Sure, it should simply look like `subprocess.call(r'curl -X POST -d "{\"variable_name\": \"${variable_content}\"}" 0.0.0.0:5000/query --header "Content-Type:application/json"', shell=True)`.  Without the `r` it would need to be `subprocess.call('curl -X POST -d "{\\"variable_name\\": \\"${variable_content}\\"}" 0.0.0.0:5000/query --header "Content-Type:application/json"', shell=True)`

Comment: Why don't you do that using ```requests```?